# C++ compiler ignores overloaded constructor

Tags: c++, qt

My Qt class has two constructors:

```
explicit ConVar(const QString &name, const QString &def, 
                NGlobalCmd::VarCallback callback = NULL, 
                const QString &desc = "", 
                NGlobalCmd::CMDFLAGS flags = 0, 
                bool hasMin = false, float min = 0.0, 
                bool hasMax = false, float max = 0.0, 
                QObject *parent = 0);

explicit ConVar(const QString &name, const QString &def, 
                /* This is the new line */
                CommandManager* manager, ListedConsoleCommand** list,
                NGlobalCmd::VarCallback callback = NULL, 
                const QString &desc = "",
                NGlobalCmd::CMDFLAGS flags = 0, bool hasMin = false, 
                float min = 0.0f, bool hasMax = false, 
                float max = 0.0f, QObject* parent = 0);
```

However, when I attempt to create an instance of the class using parameters that fit the second constructor, I get an error saying that a CommandManager pointer cannot be converted to a callback pointer (ie. the compiler does not attempt to use the second constructor). Is there any reason why this would happen? The strange thing is that the test Qt project I created which references this class's library does not suffer from the same error, whereas my actual application project (referencing the same library) does.

---

**Edit**

Header file in which the class is defined:

```
static const QString compileDate(__DATE__);
static const QString compileTime(__TIME__);
static ConVar g_compile_version("g_compile_version",
                                compileDate + " " + compileTime,
                                g_pCommandManager,
                                &g_pCommandList,
                                NULL,
                                "Date and time of last compile.",
                                NGlobalCmd::CMDFLAG_READONLY);
```

Error:

```
ConVar::ConVar(const QString &, const QString &,
               NGlobalCmd::VarCallback, const QString &, 
               NGlobalCmd::CMDFLAGS, bool, float, bool, 
               float, QObject*): 
cannot convert parameter 3 from 'ListedCommandManager *' 
                             to 'NGlobalCmd::VarCallback' 
- There is no context in which this conversion is possible.
```

ListedCommandManager is a derived class of CommandManager.

---

**Edit**

Have narrowed the issue down further. Compiles succeed if the ListedCommandManager header is included, but I'm not quite sure why.

```
/**
 * @brief Extends the CommandManager class by providing functionality to
 * traverse a list of ListedConsoleCommands when the
 * manager is created.
 */
class ICONSOLESHARED_EXPORT ListedCommandManager : public CommandManager
{
public:
    /**
     * @brief Constructor.
     * @param parent QObject parent, if applicable.
     */
    explicit ListedCommandManager(QObject* parent = 0);

    /**
     * @brief Constructor with a pointer to a list to traverse.
     * @param listHead When constructed, the manager will traverse the list
     * whose head is pointed to by this parameter.
     * @param parent QObject parent, if applicable.
     */
    explicit ListedCommandManager(ListedConsoleCommand* listHead,
                                  QObject* parent = 0);

    /**
     * @brief Destructor.
     */
    virtual ~ListedCommandManager() {}

    /**
     * @brief Traverse the list specified by the head and register each
     * console command to the manager.
     * @param listHead Head element of the list of ListedConsoleCommand
     * objects.
     */
    void traverse(ListedConsoleCommand* listHead);
};
```

Comment: Show your usage. And the exact types of all parameters.

Comment: And the exact error message.

Comment: In case it helps: the difference between the first and second constructor is that the second provides a command manager for the object to attempt to register with; if the manager is not yet created, the object attaches itself to the list pointer. The first constructor just treats both of these as NULL.

Comment: As an aside, those are *massive* argument lists! You may want to examine the responsibilities of `ConVar`.

Comment: It's literally a mimic of Valve's console variable class, as I need to work with some of their stuff. I based my argument list off the SourceMod API: http://docs.sourcemod.net/api/index.php?fastload=show&id=475&

Comment: what is NGlobalCmd::VarCallback ?

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong. Please provide a small example that can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out - the global command manager I'm trying to use in the constructor is defined in a header file, which I include, but ListedCommandManager is only forward-declared so without including ListedCommandManager.h the compiler doesn't know it's a derived class from CommandManager. Thanks to all who offered help.

Comment: By the way, you can accept your own answer so this doesn't show up anymore in the unanswered query.